# Multiple If Else with WP Query in Wordpress

Tags: wp-query

Could anybody help me with this?

I want to have **max 3 post** from this query:

category name: activities
But if the post is labeled with the tag private there must be a link with the words *private link*.
Otherwise the words are *public link*.

Could somebody explain and show me how to do this?

Thank you so much for this!

CODE:

```
<?php $wpb_all_query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => 'activities', 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => 3)); ?>

<div class="row">
    <?php if ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) :
        while ($wpb_all_query->have_posts()) : $wpb_all_query->the_post();
            $wpb_link_query = new WP_Query(array('category_name' => 'activities', 'tag' => 'private', 'post_type' => 'post', 'post_status' => 'publish'));
            if ($wpb_link_query->have_posts()) :
                while ($wpb_link_query->have_posts()) : $wpb_link_query->the_post(); ?>
                    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">private link</a>
                <?php endwhile;
                wp_reset_postdata();
            else : ?>
                <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">public link</a>
        <?php endif;
        endwhile;
        wp_reset_postdata();
    else : ?>
        <p><?php _e('Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.'); ?></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```